# Finding position of elements in perl

Tags: arrays, perl

I am having the hardest time with the question. I am new to programming and I can not figure out how to select the amino acid at the position the user asks. Here is my question:

This is my array:

```
@newarray = ('Phe', 'Val', 'Asn', 'Gln', 'His',
             'Leu', 'Cys', 'Asp', 'Ser', 'His');
```

The Question asks to Ask the user to enter a number between 1 and the number of amino acids in the polypeptide, and print the amino acid in that position (e.g. if the user enters "4" the program should print "Gln"

This is what I have so far:

```
@newarray = ('Phe', 'Val', 'Asn', 'Gln', 'His',
             'Leu', 'Cys', 'Asp', 'Ser', 'His'); 

print "Please print a number between 1 and 10\n";

chomp ($variable_name = <STDIN>)
```

Comment: You could try `print $newarray[$variable_name - 1], "\n";`

Comment: Thank you so much! That completely worked!

Comment: A small point, but I would change `$variable_name` to something more like `$amacid_position`. It's a small thing in a case like this, but choosing descriptive names is a good habit to get into early.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: `@newarray` and `$variable_name` are terrible names for your variables. Variable names should describe the data that they contain.

Answer (score 2):

To print the value at index `($variable_name - 1)` from the array `@newarray`, you can do:

```
print $newarray[$variable_name - 1], "\n";
```

See [`perlintro`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlintro.html#Perl-variable-types) for more information.